# AngularJS non-alphabetic orderBy in one of three columns

Tags: angularjs, sorting

I have a table of data which is three columns. The first two columns should be sorted alphabetically but the third column (value) needs a custom sort: high, medium, low or low, medium, high when reversed.

I have the alphabetical sorting working so far, but having trouble with the custom sort of the 3rd column (value).

JS

```
(function(angular) {
'use strict';
angular.module('orderByExample2', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
var items = [
  {name: 'name1', type: 'Web',    value: 'high'},
  {name: 'name2', type: 'Email',  value: 'medium'},
  {name: 'name3', type: 'DNS',    value: 'medium'},
  {name: 'name4', type: 'Web',    value: 'high'},
  {name: 'name5', type: 'Web',    value: 'medium'},
  {name: 'name6', type: 'Email',  value: 'high'},
  {name: 'name7', type: 'Web',    value: 'low'},
  {name: 'name8', type: 'FTP',    value: 'low'},
  {name: 'name9', type: 'Web',    value: 'high'}

];

$scope.propertyName = 'value';
$scope.reverse = false;
$scope.items = items;

$scope.sortBy = function(propertyName) {
  $scope.reverse = ($scope.propertyName === propertyName) ? 
!$scope.reverse : false;
  $scope.propertyName = propertyName;
};
}]);
})(window.angular);
```

HTML

```
<body ng-app="orderByExample2">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <pre>Sort by = {{propertyName}}; reverse = {{reverse}}</pre>
    <hr/>
    <button ng-click="propertyName = null; reverse = false">Set to default</button>
    <hr/>
    <table class="items">
      <tr>
        <th>
          <button ng-click="sortBy('name')">Name</button>
          <span class="sortorder" ng-show="propertyName === 'name'" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}"></span>
        </th>
        <th>
          <button ng-click="sortBy('type')">Type</button>
          <span class="sortorder" ng-show="propertyName === 'type'" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}"></span>
        </th>
        <th>
          <button ng-click="sortBy('value')">Value</button>
          <span class="sortorder" ng-show="propertyName === 'value'" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}"></span>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:propertyName:reverse">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.type}}</td>
        <td>{{item.value}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/zBKd3ot22NGZd0y5XTow?p=preview

Comment: Read the documentation of orderBy: you can pass a function rather than a property name, and the result of that function will be used for sorting, so you can return 0 for low, 1 for medium and 2 for high from that function, for example. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy#orderBy-arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jb-nizet says, you will need a custom function here that would return the value to order each element by. This is a way to implement that function:

```
function sortingValue(e) {
  return ['high', 'medium', 'low'].indexOf(e.value);
}
```

I've made a [fork of your Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/WsyFP9g9pZRPBhe48BY6?p=preview).

Comment: Fantastic nicooga and NB Nizet. Thanks for the help.  I was close. Bonus question then.  How do we make the default/initial sort the value?

Comment: You could simply call `$scope.sortBy('something')` or `$scope.sortByValue()` as soon as possible inside your controller.